# Shrink configuration & content database in Sharepoint DBs

Tags: shrink, sharepoint

There was some argument between me and a college about for how we should shrink DBs. We knew that shrinking should be manual and only if required.

We run in a case that configuration DBs reached to 10 GB. My debate question here is shrinking to 10 mb is good choice , or leave it to 1 GB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it at 10GB, it will grow on you. If you absolutely need to shrink the datafile for the configuration database then don't go to the smallest possible option but leave some headroom.